# How to modify a pulse with a very narrow on duty time to a squarewave like pulse?

Tags: pwm, pulse, duty-cycle

[image]

I have the pulse as seen above. I need to convert this to a pulse without affecting its frequency but modifying its on time. It gives problem when sampling it for some reason, so I need to convert this pulse train to a one with around 50% duty cycle and I also want to remove the offset i.e pulse will be from around 0 to 5V. Any suggestions?

Comment: purely in analogue or is a microprocessor available? how fixed is the frequency?

Comment: Use a monostable? Maybe you considered this but have a valid reason not to use one?

Comment: If not a monostable you can use a diode feeding an RC (low pass) in front of a schmitt triggered buffer or inverter.

Comment: Are you looking for the tiny pulse to expand to the 50% point for any frequency of pulses, or do you know that the frequency is fixed? If fixed, a multivibrator works fine... if not, it's a harder problem, where you'd have to predict a 50% and each cycle make better predictions based on the last one.

Comment: What frequency range is your pulse train?  Min frequency to Max frequency?

Comment: but wait a second the input frequency is not constant it is changing. do you still suggest the same ?????

Comment: Is it acceptable to delay the output? Is 1/fmin an acceptable delay? What is fmin (Min frequency)? Is 50% duty-cycle an absolute requirement? Does this need to be accurate for every cycle or is something like a PLL acceptable?

Comment: "It gives problem when sampling it for some reason" ... What exactly are you trying to do? What is the minimum pulse width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design a monostable multivibrator with time period = half the time period of your signal.

Then feed your input signal as trigger to this multivibrator. You will get square wave with 50% duty cycle and you can get desired output voltage depending on the multivibrator design.

**Example:**
Consider the [monostable multivariator using 555](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Monostable) given below. The output will be normally low. If a low voltage comes as trigger, the output will be high for a duration of \$1.1RC\$ seconds. And then will come back to logic low and will remain there till the next pulse comes.

[image: 555-monoshot]

Choose the value for R and C such that \$1.1RC = \dfrac{1}{2f}\$. Where \$f\$ is the frequency of your signal (which should be fed as the trigger signal). Then you will get an output with frequency \$f\$ but duty cycle = 50%.

The output voltage levels will be Vcc and GND.

P.S:
1. C is the capacitor at pin no.6. For capacitor at pin.5, 0.01uF is usually used.
2. Trigger should be a negative pulse.

Comment: will frequency of the pulses remain the same? what are the values of capacitors and resistors?

Comment: @user16307 Pls read this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Monostable). It will help you to understand more.

Comment: but wait a second the input frequency is not constant it is changing. do you still suggest the same ?????

Comment: In that case, it is not possible to get 50% duty cycle. But you can produce a pulse of fixed width. But the circuit must be designed for highest input frequency.

Comment: pulse of fixed width is not useful, it means same frequency. check out my original problem at the question. I need the pulse to have around %50 duty cycle but original varying input frequency shouldn't change at all, sine i need to count the pulses. the reason is sampling problem for a very narrow ON period pulse.

Comment: This circuit can increase the width of input pulse. It will preserve the input frequency also. But sorry about 50% duty cycle.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a servo signal for a hobby r/c servo (0.5ms - 1.5ms @ ~200hz)
The question looks like you are trying to drive a motor.

Perhaps your question is aiming to low? Perhaps expand more on what your bigger goal is.

Assuming that this is an R/C servo signal (the signal coming from the receiver), and you want to drive a dc load (like a motor), the easiest way is to buy an R/C hobby ESC (Electronic Speed Controller) for brushed motors.
  These ESC modules convert the servo pulse to a PWM output at the rated current and voltage.
  Typically, a 1ms pulse will be zero output, and as the pulse gets longer, the PWM increases in the forward rotation, reaching 100% PWM at ~1.5-2ms. If the pulse is shorter, the PWM increases in hte reverse direction. This is for driving an R/C car.
  If you do not need the reverse feature, ESC's for R/C planes do not reverse, the center position is 50% PWM.